# SQL rewriting Regular Expression to cater for two conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have the following, I would like to extract the 5th piece of data which should be 2021, the code I have which works is:

```
UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(string_field_0,r'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')) As Year
```

This works fine BUT as you can see in like 1-3 instead of being 2021 its written as 21.

What code would I use to to cater for both? Aim is to get 2021 as a result. Thanks!!!

```
P2_LLP_X211_L332_21_V1.xls
P2_LLP_X211_L332_21_V1.xls
P2_LLP_X211_L332_21_V1.xls
P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls
P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls
P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls
P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls
P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls
```

Comment: please don't post images, nobody wants to type that in see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question , also if the structure is always the same use substring_index

Comment: Updated - thanks
OK il take a look at substring_index 
Would a regular expression not work in this case?

Comment: `[0-9][0-9]{2,4}` should work

Comment: You are using MySQL?

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for your input but unfortunately this is returning a NULL value....
Any other suggestions?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch yes its for Google BigQuery

Comment: Use `SPLIT(string_field_0, '_')` and get 5th element from the array. Something like `SELECT SPLIT(string_field_0, '_')[ORDINAL(5)]`...

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Google BigQuery. You can use this query to get the years as four-digit years. This query is using [`SPLIT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) to get the fifth part of the filename. By using `CONCAT` and `RIGHT` you can get the year as four-digit number.

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('20', SPLIT(string_field_0, '_')[OFFSET(4)]), 4) 
FROM table_name
```

Another solution similar to your solution using [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract):

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('20', TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(string_field_0 , r'_([0-9]{2}){1,2}_'), '_')), 4)
FROM table_name
```

---

You can use this query using [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) to get the year area and [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to remove the underscore of the found value to get just the number.

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '_' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_field_0, '_([0-9]{2}){1,2}_')) 
FROM table_name
```

To get the year as four-digit value you can use the following solution using [`MAKEDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate) and [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year):

```
SELECT YEAR(MAKEDATE(TRIM(BOTH '_' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_field_0, '_([0-9]{2}){1,2}_')), 1)) 
FROM example
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=136470d9172e98091dfbc22e2306080a)

Answer (score 0):

When the structure is always the same

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX (`filename`,'_',-2),'[0-9]+'))
```

To transform that again in 4 digits you need to add some stirn manipulation, but hat isn't getting any prettiert

```
SELECT 
IF (LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX (`filename`,'_',-2),'[0-9]+')) = 4
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX (`filename`,'_',-2),'[0-9]+')
, CONCAT('20',REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX (`filename`,'_',-2),'[0-9]+')))
FROM tab1
```

Or much shorter

```
SELECT YEAR(MAKEDATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX (`filename`,'_',-2),'[0-9]+') ,1)) FROM tab1
```

see [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04d9ce65e2735fc80e491bec9b4aadc2)

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to get 2021 as an output even when its written as 21

Answer (score 0):

You can match on 2 or 4 digits between underscores.  Then just `lpad()` with "20" to get the prefix:

```
with t as (
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_21_V1.xls' as string_field union all
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_21_V1.xls' as string_field union all
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_21_V1.xls' as string_field union all
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls' as string_field union all
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls' as string_field union all
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls' as string_field union all
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls' as string_field union all
       select 'P2_LLP_X211_L332_2021_V1.xls'
)
select t.*,
       lpad(regexp_extract(string_field, '_([0-9]{2,4})_'), 4, '20') as year
from t
```